# returning a sorted array to print in main method

Tags: c#

```
public static double bubblesort( double [] testgrades, int grades)
{
    double[] sorted = new double[grades];

    for (int i = 0; i < testgrades.Length; i++)
        for (int j = 1; j < testgrades.Length - 1; j++)
        {
            if (testgrades[j] > testgrades[j + 1])
            {
                double tmp = testgrades[j];
                testgrades[j] = testgrades[j + 1];
                testgrades[j + 1] = tmp;
            }

            return testgrades;
        }
```

The error says `can return type double[] to double`.
Also saying no return value and not letting me use the name bubble sort for the new method

Comment: The error is self-explanatory! change your return type

Comment: You can't return a `double[]`, because the method's return type is `double`. Fix the typo in the method signature.

Comment: 1) Please post compilable examples, you are missing semicolons and brackets. 2) Use proper spelling and grammar, please. 3) You probably want to return `sorted`, not `testgrades`. 4) You are sorting an array of doubles, therefore you should a return value of `double[]`, not simply a `double`.

Answer (score 0):

You have to options:

```
public static void bubblesort(ref double [] testgrades, int grades)
 . ...
   //  return testgrades <-- don't return anything, testgrades it's already sorted
```

or:

```
public static double[] bubblesort(ref double [] testgrades, int grades)
//... everything else remains the same, just change the signature
```